# Writing unit tests with mocking of static methods in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, powermock

I'm new to writing tests in general. The class that I need to test has one method and it needs to be tested:

```
public String run(final Map<String, Dataset> datasets)
            throws ApiException {

        final String sourcePath = ElementsUtil.getElementFromDatasets(inputElementNames.get(0), datasets).getValue();
        final String destinationPath = ElementsUtil.getElementFromDatasets(inputElementNames.get(1), datasets).getValue();

        final File source = new File(sourcePath);
        final File destination = new File(destinationPath);

        if (source.exists()) {
            if (source.isDirectory()) {
                final IOFileFilter filter = new WildcardFileFilter(pattern);
                final Iterator<File> it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(source, filter, null);

                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    final File file = it.next();
                    moveFileToDirectory(file, destination);
                }
            } else {
                moveFileToDirectory(source, destination);
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Source file/folder at path {} doesn't exist.", sourcePath);
        }

        return "0";
    }
```

At first, with my limited knowledge of writing unit tests, my unit test looked like this:

```
@Test(description = "Test in case the source is a file.")
    public void moveFileTest1() {

        // setup
        final String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".txt";
        final String folderName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final Element source = new Element("source", "./" + fileName);
        final Element destination = new Element("destination", "./" + folderName);

        ...

        final Path sourcePath = Paths.get(source.getValue());
        final Path destinationPath = Paths.get(destination.getValue());
        final Path fileDestination = Paths.get(destination.getValue() + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            Files.createFile(sourcePath);
            Files.createDirectory(destinationPath);

            // exercise
            moveFile.run("", datasets, null);

            // verify
            Assert.assertEquals(Files.exists(fileDestination), true);
            Assert.assertEquals(Files.exists(sourcePath), false);
        } catch (ApiException | IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception : ", e);
        } finally {

            // teardown
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(sourcePath);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in teardown: ", e);
            }
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(fileDestination);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in teardown: ", e);
            }
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(destinationPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in teardown: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

After reading some articles about unit testing I found out that my test isn't exactly testing a unit since my method depends on different util methods. Also I found out about mocking objects in tests and how everything should be mocked. My question is:  Should I use mocking in each of these util methods/new object calls etc. or is there a different approach? How would you test this piece of code?

Comment: Where do those `Utils` objects come from?

Comment: @chrylis `ElementsUtil` is a part of the project written by me, and `FileUtils` is apache commons library.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is called integration testing. Integration testing is testing an object/method without mocking nothing, on real data or data that you produce during the test itself. What integration testing does is to test both your unit, the units that your unit uses and the flow of the use. If you would like to test only your unit you should mock all other units that your unit uses and create flows of those units doing their job successfully or not. Meaning you should replicate a test in which a used unit throws an exception/returns a value that you don't expect as a good value(only if it really can do it) and return a value that you do expect and now how to work with.
Usually when writing tests you do both kinds of testing, unit and integration tests

Answer (score 0):

There is such good test principle as "**Don't Mock What You Don't Own**". What doesn't it mean? It means your shouldn't mock/stub any interface which you cannot control, even if this interface has been written by your company, but not by your team.

But what about writing unit tests, not integration tests, where you may want to mock all classes except a class which is being tested? Indeed, this is a really tricky question. And an answer more about system design than about testing. You may read about how the issue could be resolved [here](https://blog.8thlight.com/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html) and [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own).

What does it means for your?

As your mentioned `ElementsUtil` has been written by you, so this class exactly should be mocked. How? It depends is it the legacy code or new code which you're writing now. If you have legacy code - then you need [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method), otherwise you may change design and use an instance of `ElementsUtil`.

For example, divide the `ElementsUtil` class into three classes: `Elements`- interface, `ElementsImpl`- implementation, `ElementsUtil` - class with static access to keep compatibility. The `ElementsUtil` may have method

`public static Elements getInstance()`

And the method could be used by class which contains `run` method in constructor. But you may provide either constructor with parameter or setter. By the way, as I remember Mockito can inject mocks into private fields. After this refactoring you don't need PowerMock and can use only Mockito.

Now about `FileUtils`. The class doesn't belong to you, so if follow good practice, then this class should be mock. But `FileUtils` works with file and it will already be integration tests. So answer - the `FileUtils` should be wrapped by a new your class.